# Rails - Modular many-to-many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Context**

In the context of a Ruby on Rails application, in a school's project.

Let's consider the context of a team-based game, with many characters to choose from. I want to represent affinities between two characters in different context, which means whether two characters are being teamed-up or are facing each other or even when one is present in the game while the other is missing.

I would then have tables that looks something like this in my database

- Characters
- Ally-Relation
- Enemy-Relation
- PlayingSingle-Relation

Each of these `<name>-Relation` tables represents a many-to-many relation between Characters, with an additional score that represents the strongness of the relation

Of course, relations between character are subject to changes. We might decide for any reason that a relation has become irrelevant, or another relation that we didn't thought of before just appeared.

In terms of display, we want to look for both the best and worst other characters in a specific relation.

**Question**

I came up with something like this.

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base    
  scope :best, ->(character_id) {
    Character.find(where(character_left: character_id).order("score desc").limit(5).pluck(:character_right))
  }
end
```

Where `character_left` and `character_right` are the two characters to be considered for in the relation and the score is the strenght of the bond.

However, when fetching data, my teacher thinks it would be best to have scopes in the Characters model to find both the best and worst other character in a specific relation. This, because the teammate that is doing, say, the HTML code don't give a damn about the structure of the Relations when he wants to display characters. He told me about using `has_and_belongs_to_many` and he sketched me some code he would expects that looks something like `Character.best(:relation)` to fetch the data.

While I think what I did is better (obviously :) ). Having the scopes that will fetch Characters from within the Relation models, as they subject to appear and disappear keeps the request relation specifics. This prevents us from modifying the Characters model every time we fumble with the Relations.
Having somethings that looks like `Relation.best(:hero)` seems cleaner to me.

What do you think about it ? What are good practices around this very specific situation. Are there any right way to apply and use modular many-to-many relation s in a Ruby on Rails application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on the right track with a `score` column and using that to order the relations. However you need to account for the fact that a character can be in either column in the join model.

```
class Character
  has_many :relationships_as_left, foreign_key: 'left_id'
  has_many :relationships_as_right, foreign_key: 'right_id'
end

# renamed to not get it mixed up with ActiveRecord::Relation
class Relationship
  belongs_to :left, class_name: 'Character'
  belongs_to :right, class_name: 'Character'
end
```

You want to make sure to setup a unique index and the correct foreign keys:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.references :left, index: true, foreign_key: false
      t.references :right, index: true, foreign_key: false
      t.integer :score, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :relationships, :characters, column: :left_id
    add_foreign_key :relationships, :characters, column: :right_id
    add_index :relationships, [:left_id, :right_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Querying this table is kind of tricky since Character can be referenced in `relationships.left_id` or `relationships.right_id`.

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left, class_name: 'Character'
  belongs_to :right, class_name: 'Character'

  def self.by_character(c)
    sql = "relationships.left_id = :id OR relationships.right_id = :id"
    where( sql, id: c.id )
  end

  def self.between(c1, c2)
    where(left_id: [c1,c2]).merge(where(right_id: [c1,c2]))
  end

  def other_character(c)
     raise ArgumentError unless c == left || c == right
     c == left ? right : left
  end
end
```

The `between` method requires a little explaination:

```
where(left_id: [c1,c2]).merge(where(right_id: [c1,c2]))
```

This generates the following query:

```
SELECT 
   "relationships".* FROM "relationships" 
WHERE 
   "relationships"."left_id" IN (1, 2) 
AND 
   "relationships"."right_id" IN (1, 2)
```

Also both you and your professor are wrong - a scope on `Character` will not work since scopes are class level, what you want is to check the relations on an instance.

```
class Character

  def worst_enemies(limit = 10)
    relations = Relationship.joins(:left, :right)
                            .by_character(self)
                            .order('relationship.score ASC')
                            .limit(limit)
    relations.map do |r|
      r.other_character(self)
    end
  end
end
```

You could possibly do this more elegantly with a subquery.